# How to efficiently work with large complex numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, complex-numbers, memory-efficient

For my research I am working with  large numpy arrays consisting of complex data.

```
arr = np.empty((15000, 25400), dtype='complex128')
np.save('array.npy'), arr)
```

When stored they are about 3 GB each. Loading these arrays is a time consuming process, which made me wonder if there are ways to speed this process up

One of the things I was thinking of was splitting the array into its complex and real part:

```
arr_real = arr.real 
arr_im = arr.imag
```

and saving each part separately. However, this didn't seem to improve processing speed significantly. There is some documentation about working with large arrays, but I haven't found much information on working with complex data. Are there smart(er) ways to work with large complex arrays?

Comment: if you have a lot of `0` (~70+%),  you can save `real` and `image` parts separately (using `float64` dtype) as __sparse__ arrays - that would reduce the size of those arrays dramatically in memory and on the disk

Comment: Writing or loading 3GB to/from disk takes a while, there is not really a way around that in general. However, there are two possibilities depending on the data: **1.** If the data contains many zeros you can use a [sparse representation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/sparse.html) (as suggested above). **2.** If the data is highly structured [compression](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html#numpy.savez_compressed) may relieve the i/o bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Unfortunately the data consists of radar images, which are not sparse or structured. I 'll try experimenting with different ways of saving and loading the arrays.

Comment: @kwant Images are usually well suited for compression but i guess radar images are noisy which could be a problem. Have you tried it yet? I'd be interested in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need parts of the array in memory, you can load it using [memory mapping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.load.html):

```
arr = np.load('array.npy', mmap_mode='r')
```

From the docs:

> A memory-mapped array is kept on disk. However, it can be accessed and
>   sliced like any ndarray. Memory mapping is especially useful for
>   accessing small fragments of large files without reading the entire
>   file into memory.

Comment: I think this might be useful, since I am processing a part of each image step by step.